# A formula that outputs numbers in sequence despite skipping cells

Tags: excel-formula, sequence

Can one output 1, 2, 3, etc. but have 2 empty cells between each number?

This doesn't necessarily start in B.

The empty cells can remain empty without a formula.

Required output:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 |  |  | 2 |  |  | 3 |  |  | 4 |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick some cell, say **C7**, and enter 1.

In **D7** enter:

```
=IF(MOD(COLUMNS($A:B),3)=1,1+MAX($C$7:C7),"")
```

and copy across.

[image]

Comment: Nice! I just wish there was a way to include C7 in the formula itself instead of manually writing 1.

Answer (score 1):

With Office 365 we can use SEQUENCE:

```
 =IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(,4*3,0),3)=0,INT(SEQUENCE(,4*3,1,1/3)),"")
```

Put that in the first cell desired.  You can change the `4`s to the total number desired. And it will spill across.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:H1)

Comment: Not sure I understand, there's no input to grab, only a request to return an output as per the question.

Comment: ok I taught you were looking for the opposite